# "Mona {went/has gone/would go/used to go} to the library thrice a week when she was young."

Tags: exam-questions

> Mona ____ to the library thrice a week when she was young.
> a. went
> b. has gone
> c. would go
> d. used to go

I think the right answer is "went" as "used to" can not be used to say how times an event happened.  What about you?

Comment: It's non-standard "Indian English". Mainstream Anglophone today would almost *never* use ***thrice*** in such contexts (except facetiously). It's also a garbage "test", because ***all except 'b' are perfectly acceptable verbs for the context***. Most likely the idiot who set this test thinks the "right" answer is 'c', but that's only if you want to pass the test - it's got nothing to do with *real* English.

Comment: (It's also mistranscribed, since I now realise that 'b' should in fact be ***has gone***, not ***has grown***. And *that's* a truly bizarre "typo", implying that the author barely knows English *at all*.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a *seriously* bad "test"

Answer (score 2):

All three of "went", "would go" and "used to go" can be used.  The time phrase is "past" so a past tense must be used.

"Went" is particularly used for specific past events. However, it has general use for talking about the past.  It is possible, but perhaps not the best choice.

"Used to go" and "would go" can both be used to talk about past habits.  "Would go" is rather rarer and rather more formal.  Both can be used with words like "thrice" to indicate the frequency of the habit.

"Used to" and "would" can be used with a phrase to indicate the frequency of a past habit, not the number of times it occurred.  So "I used to play tennis twice a week" is correct.  But "I used to play tennis twice" is incorrect.

"has gone" (I'm correcting the obvious typo) is a present tense, so it can't be used.

The word "thrice" is rare and formal, so perhaps "would go" is the best option.  But the overall impression of "I would go to the library thrice a week" is of a person who is trying to impress me by using rare words and rare grammar, rather than someone who is actually is fluent in English.

Comment: According to practical english usage by Michael swan used to isn't used to say how many times an event happened.

Comment: It can be used to indicate the frequence of a past habit, not the number of times it occurred.  So "I used to play tennis twice a week" is correct.  But "I used to play tennis twice" is incorrect.